# Word Office Js Update a document Word, Compressed and check

Tags: angular, ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I’m working on a **addin**, I did tutos; So, I can add texts, paragraphs and clear.

I am trying to get all the document with **getFileAsync**.

Found [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word):

First, with **Office.FileType.Text**: my raw data was correct, I failed my encoding, it was not proper but the result.value was what I wanted.

Later, my aim is to get a file from a service, .docx or zip, update the document in my Add-in and send it back.

For the moment, I do not have a “back”, I am working on document open by myself.
So, I do not have any service where I could send or save my file.

I am using **Office.FileType.Compressed** to get the whole document (after update), how can I check if my document is still correct (data and Style)?

I know with the FileType.Text way, it’s working (I got the correct value), but I would like to keep the edition (color, size...).

Do I have a method in the Office Js library (or **angular5** without new module) to open/display the result of my **getFileAsync** directly in my Word Document?  (I am a beginner for both of them).

In the future, what is the correct way to load and open the document get by my services in Word (office Js)?

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of alternatives.

1. You can insert a document from whatever source (as long as is
   base64-encoded) into your currently opened document using the
   [insertFileFromBase64 method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=office-js#insertfilefrombase64-base64file--insertlocation-).
2. You can also open the document
       in a brand new Word window. (using application.createDocument API)

[Here is a script lab sample](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/ff1b918cf0f04ed6af633d0201d92f8a) on how to do both. FYI: script lab is
    an add-in we use to share code snippets, learn how to use it on
    https://aka.ms/scriptlab

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank for your answer. So i have to encode my data obtained (AsyncResult.value) and use insertFileFromBase64 method, but if i correctly got i can't use "btoa" with "an array of bytes" ?

Comment: in the document that you cited there is a sample on how to return the base64 after using getFileAsync (note that the sample is getting many slices of the file and econding them as bas64) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word